# All playOrm tests failing

Tags: playorm

I just downloaded the last version of the code and tried "ant testCheckin".

All tests failed. What could I be doing wrong? I tried both IN_MEMORY and CASSANDRA configurations in factorySingleton

---

### T E S T S

Running com.alvazan.test.TestColumnSlice
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mvalle/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/mvalle/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.1/logback-classic-1.0.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.075 sec <<< FAILURE!
testDecimalColumnSlice(com.alvazan.test.TestColumnSlice)  Time elapsed: 1993 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassSingle cannot be cast to com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.data.MetaClassInheritance
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForField.processToOne(ScannerForField.java:342)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForField.processManyToOne(ScannerForField.java:202)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:185)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:169)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:108)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:67)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:41)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
    at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:80)
    at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
    at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:51)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:26)
    at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:21)
    at com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton.createFactory(FactorySingleton.java:56)
    at com.alvazan.test.FactorySingleton.createFactoryOnce(FactorySingleton.java:37)
    at com.alvazan.test.TestColumnSlice.createEntityManager(TestColumnSlice.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKAY, we found it.  This bug is now fixed in PlayOrm.  It turns out the scan scans classes in a different order and there was a bug revealed when scanned in a different order.  This bug is not fixed so it can still be scanned in any order.

I had someone else check it out and run ./build and his ran fine, sooooo to debug your problem...

1. Run git status and see what changes you have
2. I added some "debug" level logs and turned on debugging so update to latest(these will help me debug further plus I need more logs in those areas)
3. Run TestKeyTypes.testIntegerType and cut and paste the logs in the question so I can debug it further

My guess is you have changes with some kind of inheritance entity that is not correctly throwing an exception of "you can't do that"(and I have TONS of those but may be missing one).

Dean

Comment: got last version, everything ran fine now